# Spring Find by unique properties

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Given 1 relational table

| Doctor_ID | Client_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

And I want all the occurrences where client_id is not equals to 3, ignoring the same doctor_id.

In this example, I would only get the 4th row...

| Doctor_ID | Client_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 |

How could I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query with `NOT EXISTS` will give you the results needed.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM myTable b WHERE a.Doctor_ID = b.Doctor_ID AND Client_ID = 3
)
```

The `NOT EXISTS` will filter out ant doctor id that has a client id equals to 3.